# How to figure out the exact property which is not been set in Bean.Populate error [Struts]?

Tags: java, spring, struts, pojo

My application is built in Struts and I am facing an issue. When my Action for example `\getinfo.do?param=1 is called every thing works fine. A page opens and display value. Now in the same page I have placed a button to go back with value as` \getinfo.do?param=2`. Now when I am clicking this, I get the following error.

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet action in application EPS_EAR. Exception created : javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate
at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:495)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:805)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
at com.uhg.exante.online.filters.EPSAccessFilter.doFilter(EPSAccessFilter.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3933)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getIndexedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:427)
```

I know its related to ActionForm. I tried to debug the code also and verified that all the property have corresponding getter setters. In my Action Form I have a reset method which I am calling. I am resetting values there and I verified there too that all values are reseting. Still I am not able to figure out how to know the exact property value which is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Your link should be, I'm not sure about '2':

```
getinfo.do?param=2
```

and not

```
\getinfo.do\param="2"
```

Comment: To pass parameter you should use ?param=  and not \param=